# React Native crashes on real device

Tags: react-native

Can someone suggest how can i see the reason why a react-native app is crashing on a real device ?

Running it on emulator from versions from 23 to 26 everything works fine. Once run on RealDevice with any of those android versions it just crashes.

Comment: Can you please post the error log?

Comment: you should get error on console (of chrome) when you run app on device with debug. you can also use "adb logcat"

Comment: I do not have any logs. Because I am deploying the APK directly on a device. The device is not connected to the PC.

Answer (score 1):

I know its very late but someone can get benefit from this answer.
I went through the same problem and in my case the problem was

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libreactnativejni.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libglog_init.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libglog.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libgnustl_shared.so caused by: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.namaztiming/lib-main/libgnustl_shared.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit`

There is a solution to the problem that should be added to the app/build.gradle. You can also refer https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2814#issuecomment-462647801.

and it solved by adding

```
android {
  ...
  // add the following packagingOptions 
  packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
  }
}
```

if then also it's not getting solved then you can try to add the following to the `defaultConfig` in the `app/build.gradle`

```
ndk { 
abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86' 
}
```